# Measure the time database actions take with an Entity Listener

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, listener

Basically I need to count the times an object gets persisted, updated, etc. With `@PostPersist`, `@PostUpdate` and so on.

But I also need to know how long these store-actions take (only altogether), is there a way to do it with the (default) Entity Listener?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could activate the hibernate statistics: set `hibernate.generate_statistics` to `true` eigher by command line property by configuration in persistence.xml

```
...
<properties>
    ...
    <property name="hibernate.generate_statistics" value="true"/>   
<properties>
```

and add to your logging configuration

```
<logger name="org.hibernate.stat" level="DEBUG" />
```

This would tell you for each session how many SQL statments are executed and how long does it take

BTW: internally it is done by `org.hibernate.engine.internal.StatisticalLoggingSessionEventListener`

Comment: This sounds like the way to go, I hope I can use it like this (I have the restriction to use a listener for this task).

Answer (score 1):

I believe the better way to achieve this is to use AOP, intercepting the methods you want to measure and doing anything you want. Spring AOP seems perfect for this.

I know it's not related with Entity Listener, but it's just a different ideia =)

Documentation with examples: http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-framework/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/aop-api.html

Comment: It's probably a good suggestion, I just have to use a listener for it in this assignment unfortunately.